# Pass object type variable to another Class but keep structure?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-builder, flash-cs5, flash-cs4

My doubt is this:

I have this variable in this class A

```
var obj:Object = new Object()
```

and its structure:

```
obj.name = "John";
obj.age = 44;
```

I'd like to take this variable `obj` and pass it to the class B (I know how to do this) but I don't know how can I keep the structure:

`obj.name` and `obj.age`

Does anybody know this?

Comment: Can you expand on how you're passing it or describe more precisely the problem you're seeing?  If you're passing it in some way that doesn't retain the attributes/values of the object, that's a problem you'll want to address.

Comment: Please post how you are passing it to class B. If you simply send on the instance reference, the "structure" is preserved, so I'm not sure what you are doing :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are having problems then consider making a new class, then when you pass it around pass it as you new class and not just as an object.

(untested code)

```
package {
  public class SomeDude {
    public var name:String;
    public var age:int;
    public function SomeDude() {}
  }
}
```

then pass it / reference it something like:

```
var dude:SomeDude = new SomeDude();
dude.name = "John";
dude.age = 44;

otherClass.someFunction(dude);
```

Within your otherClass have a function like:

```
...
public function someFunction(theDude:SomeDude){}
...
```